# why am I being redirected to a 404 Page Not Found?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote the server.js code below:

```
// Require modules
const http = require('http');

const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

// Array of Mime Types
const mimeTypes = {
    "html" : "text/html",
    "jpeg" : "image/jpeg",
    "jpg" : "image/jpeg",
    "png" : "image/png",
    "js" : "text/javascript",
    "css" : "text/css"
};

// Create Server
const server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    const uri = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    const fileName = path.join(process.cwd(),unescape(uri));
    console.log('Loading '+ uri);
    const stats;

    try{
        stats = fs.lstatSync(filename);
    } catch(e) {
        res.writeHead(404, {'Content-type': 'text/plain'});
        res.write('404 Not Found\n');
        res.end();
        return;
    }

    // Check if file/directory
    if(stats.isFile()){
        const mimeType = mimeTypes[path.extname(fileName).split(".").reverse()[0]];
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': mimeType});

        const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
        fileStream.pipe(res);
    } else if(stats.isDirectory()){
        res.writeHead(302,{
            'Location' : 'index.html'
        });
        res.end();
    } else {
        res.writeHead(500, {'Content-type' : 'text/plain'});
        res.write('500 Internal Error\n');
        res.end();
    }
}).listen(3000);
```

I have an index.html page that simply says test and instead of rendering that in the browser I get a 404 Page Not Found. Since I tweaked the server.js file I believe the problem is there, but I am not quite sure.

Anybody see how this server code could have been written to better server the index.html file I have in the project?

Comment: I would assume the index file is in the wrong location. What does the line consolde.log('Loading ' + uri) print out? Also, in the catch(e) that writes out the 404 try to console.log(e) and console.log(e.stack). This should give you more information to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps :

```
stats = fs.lstatSync(fileName);
```

and not :

```
stats = fs.lstatSync(filename);
```

You have the wrong variable/param... it's case sensitive.

Comment: Thomas, my bad, I thought I had fixed all the filenames in my code.

Comment: There is still something not right with my code, I am thinking its in const stats; Should it be var stats;?

Comment: I'm guessing at this point... but may be add res.end(); after fileStream.pipe(res)‌​

Comment: Hi Thomas, I decided to change const stats; to var stats; and the page rendered. I am not sure what best practice is in this case, but that change worked. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: You can try this and see if it works: const stats = fs.lstatSync(filename); If it does then const variables, once assigned a value cannot change.